# Java factory pattern - load classes dynamically

Tags: java, oop, factory, factory-pattern

I have a lot of classes UNO,HAV,MAS,KOS
I want to create  a factory pattern.

```
 validator.load("UNO").validate();
```

I need dynamically load classes into validator class and return an instance.
(dynamically  set name of the class and return an instance)
My problem is: how can I return the instance of a class, if I have incompatible types?

I don't know what to write in return type of method.

The main problem in the **Validator CLASS**.

```
public SegmentAbstract load(String str) {
```

AND

```
return SegmentAbsClass.forName(identify);
```

**Main class**

```
try{
   validator.load("UNO").validate();
}catch(Exception e){
   System.out.print("No class ");
}
```

**Abstract Class (SegmentAbstract)**

```
public abstract class SegmentAbstract {

  public abstract Boolean validate();
}
```

**Class UNO**

```
public class UNA extends SegmentAbstract{

  public Boolean validate() {
    System.out.print("UNO!!");
    return true;
  }

}
```

**Class Validator**

```
public class Validator {

  public SegmentAbstract load(String str) {
    String identify = str.substring(0, 3);
    try {

      return SegmentAbsClass.forName(identify);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      return this;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to return always a new copy of the `SegmentAbstract` classes?

Comment: @Dezigo as long as your classes extend `SegementAbstract` they are not incompatible since all of them implement `validate()`. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @stacker I know an another way, using switch case.. but i don`t want  use it

Comment: But what is exactly the problem? The code seems to be ok. (Except that `catch(Exception e) { return this; }` looks suspicious for me.) Or maybe you have forgot [`newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do something like that:

```
// ISegment.java
public interface ISegment {
    Boolean validate();
}

// Uno.java
public class Uno implements ISegment {
    public Boolean validate() {
        System.out.print("UNO!!");
        return true;
    }
}

// SegmentFactory.java
public final class SegmentFactory {
    public static enum Supported {
        UNO("uno", Uno.class), /* ... */, HAV("hav", Hav.class);

        private final Class<?> clazz;
        private final String name;

        private Supported(final String name, final Class<?> clazz) {
            this.name = name;
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        public Class<?> getClazz() {
            return clazz;
        }

        public static Supported for(final String name) {
            for (final Supported s : values()) {
                if (s.name.equals(name) {
                    return s;
                }
            }
            return null; // a default one
        }
    }

    public static ISegment create(final Supported supp) {
        if (supp == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return supp.getClazz.newInstance();
    }

    private SegmentFactory() {
        // avoid instantiation
    }
}
```

usage:

```
final ISegment sa = SegmentFactory.create(SegmentFactory.Supported.for("uno"));
sa.validate();
```

**Not tested!!**

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
public interface Validator {
    boolean validate(Object obj);
}

public final class ValidatorFactory {
    private ValidatorFactory(){}

    public static Validator load(String type){
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(type);
            if (Arrays.asList(clazz.getInterfaces()).contains(Validator.class)){
                return (Validator) clazz.newInstance();
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Provided class doesn't implement Validator interface");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong class provided", e);
        } 
    }
}
```

Maybe this will help???

Comment: Thank you, but I have chosen another way.:)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html). Briefly, the idea is to create a map in your factory class (`Map<String,String>`, key is identifier, value is fully qualified class name), and add supported classes during initialization. Then you use reflection to instantiate an object in your factory method. Also, you can avoid reflection by using `Map<String, SegmentAbstract>` instead of `Map<String,String>` and adding `public abstract getNewSegment()` to your `SegmentAbstract` class.

Comment: I think it's better to use a `Map<String, Class<?>>` for refactoring.

Comment: @RC: I agree, it's just an example that hopefully pushes the OP to the right direction.